# Add join results as new column based on values from join

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, pivot

I've never done something like this, and I tried finding it on google but without result.

I have 3 tables that look like this:

**Orders:**

```
OdredID (int) PK,
UserID (int) FK,
OdredDate (datetime)
```

**Components:**

```
ComponentID (int) PK,
Name (nvarchar(50)),
Type (nvarchar(max))
```

**OrderComponent:**

```
OrderComponentID (int) PK,
OrderID (int) FK,
ComponentID (int) FK,
Value (nvarchar(max))
```

Lets say one order has 3 components with names: `[CPU, Motherboard, Memory]` and values `[1GHz, AsusP5, 2GB Kingston DDR3]`

I need a result has columns like this:

```
OrderID  UserID   Date          CPU    Motherboard   Memory
   1        1     2012-05-21    1GHz   AsusP5        2GB Kingston DDR3
```

Basically I need every join row to go as new column with name taken from `Name` column of join table and value from `Value` column.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT
  o.orderid,
  o.userid,
  MAX(CASE WHEN c.Name = 'CPU' THEN oc.Value END) AS 'CPU',
  MAX(CASE WHEN c.Name = 'Motherboard' THEN oc.Value END) AS 'Motherboard',
  MAX(CASE WHEN c.Name = 'Memory' THEN oc.Value END) AS 'Memory'
FROM orders o
INNER JOIN ordercomponents oc ON c.orderid = oc.orderId
INNER JOIN Components c ON oc.componentid = c.componentid
GROUP BY o.orderid, o.userid
```

### [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/65cf1/3)

**Note that:** This the standard SQL way to do this. But you can use the SQL Server `PIVOT` table operator to do the same thing like so:

```
SELECT  *
FROM
(
   SELECT o.orderid, o.userid, c.Name 'Name', oc.value 'value'
   FROM orders o
   INNER JOIN ordercomponent oc ON o.orderid = oc.orderId
   INNER JOIN Components c ON oc.componentid = c.componentid
 ) t 
PIVOT
(
  MAX(value)
  FOR Name IN ([CPU], [Motherboard], [Memory])
) p;
```

But this for a set of pre defined values like `[CPU], [Motherboard], [Memory]`.

For unknown number of values, you have to do it dynamically like so:

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE @query AS NVARCHAR(MAX);

select @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(c.name) 
                    from Components c
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

set @query = 'SELECT orderid, userid  ' + @cols + ' from 
             (
                 select o.orderid, o.userid, c.Name Name, oc.value value
                 FROM orders o
                 INNER JOIN ordercomponent oc ON o.orderid = oc.orderId
                 INNER JOIN Components c ON oc.componentid = c.componentid
            ) x
            pivot 
            (
                max(value)
                for name in (' + @cols + ')
            ) p '

execute(@query);
```

### [Updated SQL Fiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/65cf1/7)

Comment: Thank you very much! Works like a charm. Is there any way to this dynamically?
Example: For every Order no matter what the value of Name column is? I will have probably around 200 Components..

Comment: I try to get how this works. Why did you use MAX()? Is it because without it we would not be able to do a GROUP BY?

Comment: @DusanVasiljevic Without the `max()`, you would get multiple rows instead of one. Try it yourself, leave out the `max()` and `group by`.

Comment: @DusanVasiljevic - You have to use max because of the `GROUP BY` you cannot include a column in the select list without beeing included in the `GROUP BY` clause or with an aggregated function therefore I used a `MAX` as a workaround.

Comment: @MahmoudGamal Please, add comma in line `set @query`after the `userid`

Comment: @MahmoudGamal This is not a must, but since I will always get one result because of `where OrderID = X` is it possible to remove NULL Columns? If Field with Name = Graphics exists and it is not part of the order, this way it will still show as column with NULL value.