# Return a single row when joining table has many values

Tags: sql-server, concatenation, join

Looked around for a bit but can't find anything that resembles what I need. I have two tables that are joined on ID and the second table has multiple details about the first under different properties using the same ID. So ID 1 has properties like A, B, C etc and there are 9 of them total for each ID. I would like to return a single row per ID that has all the different properties.

Here are my tables.

```
   MAIN_Table
  ID   | Name
------ | ------
  100  | Frank
  200  | Bill
  300  | Anne


      Property_Table
  ID   | Prop  |  Value
------ | ------| -----
  100  | AA    |   $4
  100  | BB    |   ER
  200  | BB    |   AMB
  300  | AA    |   $10
  200  | AA    |   $5
  300  | BB    |   ER
```

I have tried several case statements which seem to return a row for each listed value instead of on a single line, i don't like/want this...

```
ID     |  Name    |   Prop_AA  | Prop_BB
-----  | ------   |  ------    | -------
100    |  Frank   |  $4        |  NULL
100    |  Frank   |  NULL      |  ER
200    |  Bill    |  $5        |  NULL
200    |  Bill    |  NULL      |  AMB
300    |  Anne    |  $10       |  NULL
300    |  Anne    |  NULL      |  ER
```

I would like everything to be on a single line per ID like this...

```
ID     |  Name    |   Prop AA  | Prop BB
-----  | ------   |  ------    | -------
100    |  Frank   |  $4        |  ER
200    |  Bill    |  $5        |  AMB
300    |  Anne    |  $10       |  ER
```

Comment: I seem to get a result that looks like what I want using Max(Case when prop=AA then Value) as Prop_AA but I have many other columns and have to add each of these to a group by, could this cause errors because of this? [Source for Max Statement](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13284952/add-join-results-as-new-column-based-on-values-from-join)

Answer (score 0):

I used 2 common table expressions to get the results you were needing. [Common_Table_Expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql)

```
--CTE to get Prop AA's Id & Value
WITH Prop_AA AS
(
   SELECT ID,Value
   FROM Property_Table
   WHERE Prop = 'AA'
),
--CTE to get Prop BB's Id & Value
Prop_BB AS
(
   SELECT ID,Value
   FROM Property_Table
   WHERE Prop = 'BB'
)

SELECT mt.ID,Name,aa.Value as 'Prop AA',bb.Value as 'Prop BB'
FROM MAIN_Table mt
   JOIN Prop_AA aa ON mt.ID = aa.ID -- Join Prop_AA
   JOIN Prop_BB bb ON mt.ID = bb.ID -- Join Prop_BB
ORDER BY mt.ID
```